# Reload vs Refresh

Tags: cache-control, browser-cache

I have this script

```
<?php
header("Expires: Sat, 11 Jun 2011 00:00:00 GMT");
echo "Hello World";
?>
```

It just writes "Hello World" and set the cache to expire on next Saturday.

Now, when I load this page in FireFox and click on reload button, it makes a new request to server to load the page instead of just serving it from cache (I think to ensure if `last-modified` is still valid).

However, if I put my cursor on the address bar and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, FireFox serves the contents from cache.

Why is that so? Why does in first case (reload) it makes a request to server, but in second case (refresh, I guess?) it serves from cache?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I think the terms 'refresh' and 'reload' are basically synonymous.  I see this line in RFC 2616 that describes HTTP/1.1 caching that provides a possible slight difference:

> An expiration time cannot be used to force a user agent to **refresh its display** or **reload a resource**

In other words, perhaps you could say refreshing is for displays, and reloading is for resources.  But since browsers' primary use for resources is display, I don't see a difference.

Here's a [short writeup](http://www-jo.se/f.pfleger/firefox-reload) on the terms by a developer who has dealt with browser cache control. The terms he prefers are these:

- *load*: hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> in the address bar; click on links
- *reload*: <kbd>F5</kbd>; <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>; toolbar's refresh button; Menu -> Reload
- *hard reload*: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>; <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>

(The hard reload forces the browser to bypass its cache.  For Firefox, you hold down <kbd>Shift</kbd> and press the reload button. Wikipedia has [a list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Bypass_your_cache) of how to do this for common browsers. You can test its effect on [this page](http://www.refreshyourcache.com/en/cache-test/).)

To answer your question about how Firefox decides when to refresh, here is how the [link from above](http://www-jo.se/f.pfleger/firefox-reload) explains it:

- *load*: no request happens until the cached resource expires
- *reload*: the request contains the `If-Modified-Since` and `Cache-Control: max-age=0` headers that allow the server to respond with `304 Not Modified` if applicable
- *hard reload*: the request contains the `Pragma: no-cache` and `Cache-Control: no-cache` headers and will bypass the cache

Answer (score 3):

When people refresh a page, they generally expect to see new results, so caching of the entire page doesn't make much sense.

Comment: i guess you are talking about relaod ?